# mysqldump and restore with tranditional chinese character

Tags: mysql, docker, character-encoding, cjk

I am trying to take mysql dump from docker with command:

```
docker exec testsigma_mysql /usr/bin/mysqldump -u root --password=root --default-character-set=utf8mb4 testsigma_opensource > backup.sql
```

when take restore I get the error `ERROR at line : Unknown command '\0'`

what is command to take mysqldump with tranditional chinese character ?

Comment: That of course is a locale, char set encoding issue. `'\0'` looks like part of a latin letter as wide character, You must restore with UTF-8 too with that `--default-character-set. But check first that your dump is in UTF-8.

Comment: I check the restore which with `--default-character-set=utf8` through powershell, got the same issue, if through cmd it dump completed , but It looks like the data restoration attempt wasn't successful.

Comment: @JoopEggen - `\0` is is not part of any latin letter.

Comment: @weilingshao - Can you show us what is around the `\0`?

Comment: @RickJames with **wide** characters using 2 bytes the latin character is padded with a zero `\0`. That could come soon in basically latin script, hence not showing more in the error message. _(But that is speculation.):_

Comment: @JoopEggen - The "wide characters" I know of are simply different hex values.  I have never heard of `\0` being used to widen a character.  Please explain where you see such.

Comment: In UTF-16 U+0065 = 'A' is represented as 0x00 0x65 or in little endian UTF-16LE 0x65 0x00. Unfortunately byte 0x00, '\0', terminates C strings.